# Explain file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: php, android

I am writing an android app to connect to PHP web service and through my searches in internet I faced `file_get_contents('php://input');` and I understood some parts of it's functionality but I still don't get it. What are `php://input` or `php://stdin` or stuff like that?
I've read http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and I confused much more.

Please explain it completely.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The information comes from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

When information is sent to the server via a `POST` request, it is saved in a temporary file.

The command `file_get_contents('php://input')` reads the raw information sent to PHP -- unprocessed before it ever gets put into `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` super globals.

This technique is often used when someone is uploading a file, such as an image.

EDIT:  removed <strike>`$_GET`</strike>

Comment: Very complete and helpful but is it suitable to post json data of an online game to PHP web service?

Comment: Afraid I can't answer that for certain -- but at first thought I don't see a problem with it.