# send a php webpage to folder and dispay the content as html

Tags: php, html, post

would it be possible to have a html/php template on `index.php` say for example (a news webpage template and then anyone can edit the title, paragraphs only, then on submit it then sends the webpage with the data stored to a paste bin like url so who ever visits that url say `http://localhost/news/jjeh3bndjks` they would only be able to view to content and not edit.

I would like to use something like this

```php
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $pasteID = uniqid();
    $paste = fopen("pastes/".$pasteID.".php", "w");
    $contents = $_POST['pasteContents'];
    fwrite($paste, $contents);
    header('Location: /pastes/'.$pasteID.'.php');
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="pasteContents" placeholder="write here" />
  <button type="submit" tabindex="0">submit</button>
</form>
```

but for some reason when i add another input box or try to send anymore data it fails or just gives me the last input given is there a way to send a whole page this way?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you give an example of a code that fails. And what do you mean by `fails`? Is there an error message?

Comment: not errors but it either shows nothing even though i entered text in both fields when i add another input box or even if i try the same code but change the names it jus shows me the text i entered in the second box and ignores the first box is there a way to send more code this way eg. more html tags ect?

Comment: Try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8207498/863110) answer. First `dump` the whole `POST` object see how it looks. Then, try using `ile_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: @MoshFeu var dump shows this `array(0) { }` any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `file_get_contents('php://input');`?

Comment: @MoshFeu this is var dump after i done what u said `array(1) { ["pasteContents"]=> string(14) "this is test 2" } this is test 2`

Comment: It's all good. But this is a simple question :) Quick search: [Short explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23304593/863110), example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8207498/863110

Comment: This var dump is when you are using 2 inputs or 1?

Comment: @MoshFeu it ignores the first input box of (this is test 1) which i entered, do you know a way i can get both data fields?

Comment: Can you post in the question the code you are using with the 2 inputs?

Comment: `<?php
if ($_POST) {
 $pasteID = uniqid();
 $paste = fopen("pastes/".$pasteID.".php", "w");
 $contents = $_POST['pasteContents'];
 fwrite($paste, $contents);
 #header('Location: /pastes/'.$pasteID.'.php');
 file_get_contents('php://input');
}
var_dump($_POST);
echo $_POST["pasteContents"];
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="pasteContents" placeholder="write here"/>
<input type="text" name="pasteContents" placeholder="write here"/>
<button type="submit" tabindex="0">submit</button>
</form>`

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks for your help

Comment: You have the same `name` attribute so the second one override the first.

Comment: @MoshFeu when i try it with diffrent names it shows up blank, would you be able to try this for me and show example of 2 or more fields working? i would appreachiate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` with the following code:

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo param1 . '<br />' . param2;
} else {
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="param1" value="param1" />
    <input type="text" name="param2" value="param2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

(You can test it [here](http://www.smydesign.co.il/proxy/test.php))

Although, I did success to use `$_POST` too:

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {    
    echo $_POST['param1'] . '<br />' . $_POST['param2'];
} else {
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="param1" value="param1" />
    <input type="text" name="param2" value="param2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

[Here](http://www.smydesign.co.il/proxy/test_post.php)