# UploadStringDataAsync sends nothing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uploadstring

I'm trying to send a json to a php page but result is always empty.

```
try
{
   using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
   {
      webclient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
      webclient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
      webclient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

      string result = await webclient.UploadStringTaskAsync(url,"POST",json);

      if (debug)
         Console.WriteLine(" => " + result); // array(0) { }

   }
}
```

The json string is obtained with

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchModel);
```

And json output is

```
{"term":"test","local":null,"localLabel":null,"result":null,"resultLabel":null,"genre":null,"costumer":null}
```

My url target:

```
<?php echo var_dump($_POST); ?>

//doing  $test="test" and  adding $test inside var_dump shows the right value..
```

what i'm missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304531/explain-file-get-contentsphp-input

Comment: @Jason thank you.. now it works.

Comment: Yes, as I said on my last comment, it works now.